# Account Territory is not getting automatically assigned when a new account is created

Tags: territory

When a user creates new account territory assignment rule doesn't work but when we manually run assignment rule/ edit the account then it assigns territory.

Comment: can you put a picture how you have setup

Answer (score 0):

We have one parent territory and 4 child territories.
1 child territory have another 3 child territories.

whats happening is the account assignment rule is only updating the account records with one assignment rule from 1 child territory when account is created although there are other rules  which are active too.

And when we run assignment rule manually then it updates record with all rules.